# Confusing python problem

Tags: python

As part of a large python program I have the following code:

```
for arg in sys.argv:
    if "name=" in arg:
            name = arg[5:]
            print(name)
    elif "uname=" in arg:
            uname = arg[6:]
            print(uname)
    elif "password=" in arg:
            password = arg[9:]
            print(password)
    elif "bday=" in arg:
            bday = arg[5:]
            print(bday)
    else:
            pass
```

The program expects something like:

```
python prog.py "name=Kevin" "uname=kevin" "password=something" "bday=01/01/01"
```

When I try to use "uname" later, the program fails, claiming "uname is not defined"
I added the "print()" lines to try and debug and the "print(uname)" always shows "=kevin" regardless of the index number I put there (here "6:"). The other statements seem to work fine. Is this a bug in python? I am very confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is this a bug in python?"  The odds of that are nearly zero.

Comment: Is using one of `getopt`, `optparse` or `argparse` modules not an option?

Comment: Python comes with batteries: http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#module-optparse (for Python2.6 or earlier), or http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse (for Python2.7 or better or if you install it yourself).

Comment: don't do this yourself; use a Python command-line args parser. They're built in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The elif "uname=" is never run because the string "name=" is in "uname=".   Essentially, you are overwriting your name variable.

```
>>> "name=" in "uname="
True
```

You could reorder your ifs so that so that the uname occurs before the name one.

Comment: Thank you Mark! I didn't see that. Wow. That explains a lot.

Comment: @user428582, a quick fix would be to do `if arg.startswith('whatever'):`, though using a more robust way of parsing args (e.g. optparse) would be better still...

Comment: Just printing the contents of a variable is not very helpful for debugging when you are doing it for multiple variables. Had you done `print "uname", uname` you would have seen that the "=kevin" was in the wrong variable.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look closely at this.

```
if "name=" in arg:
        name = arg[5:]
        print(name)
elif "uname=" in arg:
        uname = arg[6:]
        print(uname)
```

When I apply this to "name=Kevin", which rule works?  Just the first one, right?

When I apply this to "uname=kevin", which rule works?  First one?  Second one?  Both?  Interestingly, the first one works.  I see `name=kevin` inside `uname=kevin`.  Not what you wanted, was it?